# Mongo query to split more than two arrays without duplicate result

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to build a Mongo query for the below-mentioned record,

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "source": "Source1",
    "customer": "customer1",
    "models": [
      { "modelid": "modelid123" },
      { "modelid": "modelid124" }
    ],
    "accounts": [
      {
        "account": "acc1",
        "models": [
          { "modelid": "modelid123" },
          { "modelid": "modelid124" }
        ],
        "packages": [
          {
            "package": "p1",
            "models": [
              { "modelid": "modelid123" },
              { "modelid": "modelid125" }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "account": "acc2",
        "models": [
          { "modelid": "modelid123" },
          { "modelid": "modelid126" }
        ],
        "packages": [
          {
            "package": "p2",
            "models": [
              { "modelid": "modelid123" }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My expected o/p is

```
source    customer    account    package
Source1   customer1
Source1   customer1    acc1
Source1   customer1    acc1        p1
Source1   customer1    acc2
Source1   customer1    acc2        p2
```

As modelid123 is present at all the above levels.

I tried using $unwind aggregate functions to achieve the above but I am getting duplicate rows.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: { path: "$models", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
  { $unwind: { path: "$accounts", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
  { $unwind: { path: "$accounts.models", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
  { $unwind: { path: "$accounts.packages.models", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
  {
    $match: {
      "$and": [ { "source": "Accurate" } ],
      "$or": [
        { "models.modelId": { "$in": [ "model1234" ] } },
        { "accounts.models.modelId": { "$in": [ "model1234" ] } },
        { "accounts.packages.models.modelId": { "$in": [ "model1234" ] } }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

`Problem here is that I can not restructure the data. I can do this on the code side using Java but I want to achieve pagination also. I am using Spring data mongodb to connect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$group` to deal with duplicae. I think you can learn from my answer and correct your own one.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: { path: "$models", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
  { $unwind: { path: "$accounts", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
  { $unwind: { path: "$accounts.models", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
  { $unwind: { path: "$accounts.packages", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
  { $unwind: { path: "$accounts.packages.models", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      source: "$source",
      customer: "$customer",
      account: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $eq: [ "$models.modelid", "modelid123" ] },
          then: "$accounts.account",
          else: null
        }
      },
      package: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $and: [
              { $eq: [ "$models.modelid", "modelid123" ] },
              { $eq: [ "$accounts.packages.models.modelid", "modelid123" ] }
            ]
          },
          then: "$accounts.packages.package",
          else: null
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$$ROOT",
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$_id"
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/u-cMvnuao1t

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This really helped me. I have modified my query as per my need. The only problem I am facing is to get removed source, null, null, null .
https://mongoplayground.net/p/KjQ1xepgWea

Comment: @Shashank how about add another match in the end of pipeline in order to get rid of some documents that you don't need,

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I got it right :)

Comment: I am trying to get multiple values compared `{$eq: ['$models.modelId', '6246cf0f3a3d5c7455d5edeb']}` instead of one in above mentioned query. I am using `{$match : {'models.modelid' : {$in: ['6246cf0f3a3d5c7455d5edeb']}}}` but some how this is not working

Comment: @Shashank `{$in: ['$models.modelId', ['6246cf0f3a3d5c7455d5edeb']]}` check [this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/#mongodb-expression-exp.-in)